no USB on Pi Zero 2 w Ubuntu server 24.10 (and other 64 bit Ubuntu flavors)
I'm trying to use Ubuntu server 24.10 on a Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W.  It boots up fine, seems to work fine aside from the LED on the Pi not working, but the attached USB hat (Makerspot) cannot be accessed.
I changed to Ubuntu server 22.04.1 64-bit and got the same result.
I changed to Ubuntu server 22.04.5 LTS 64-bit and got the same result.
I changed to Ubuntu server 22.04.5 32-bit and the USB hat is perfectly usable (and the peripherals plugged into it).  Also the LED on the Pi zero is working.
24.10 has some newer packages I would like to use. I'm not sure where to go, what to check or why I cannot find anyone else that has had this problem.
Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit works fine, but again is using a terribly old version of gpsd. (3.22 is three years old and has an issue with uBlox devices). I've tried multiple times to build it from source with no luck.
lsusb with a 64-bit Ubuntu OS only shows:
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Ubuntu 22.04.5 32 bit shows 2 devices without anything plugged into the hat
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

Makerspot says you may have to disable OTG mode - which may be the key, but I cannot figure out how to do that.
